# Error in Jest test req.session.save is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest, http-mock

It giving me a error at `await req.session.save();` like req.session.save is not a function.

How I can create mock for req.session.save()?

**myController.ts**

```
static async connect(req: any, res: Response) {
    ...
    req.session.testToken = {
        refresh_token: refresh_token,
        access_token: access_token,
        expires_in: 1200
    };
    await req.session.save();

    res.json({success:true, message:'Connected'});
}
```

**myController.spec.ts**

```
descibe('test',()=> {
    let req = httpMocks.createRequest();
    let res = httpMocks.createResponse();

    it('should connected',()=> {
        myController.connect(req,res);

        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
        expect(res._isEndCalled()).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

Comment: We can't see from what you've posted what `httpMocks.createRequest()` does, presumably it would need updating, but also you're seeing exactly the problem with unit testing controllers - you're mocking what you don't own. Test this kind of thing at the _integration_ level, not down in the implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you have to create a mock for `req.session.save()`

**myController.spec.ts**

```
descibe('test',()=> {
    let req = httpMocks.createRequest({
        session: {
                save: jest.fn()
        }
    });
    let res = httpMocks.createResponse();

    it('should connected',()=> {
        myController.connect(req,res);

        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
        expect(res._isEndCalled()).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In the context of that particular test, you are not making any assertion on the `req` object, so you can just use a simple object literal.

```
let req = {
  session: {
    save: () => Promise.resolve()
  },
};
```

In case you will need to assert that the `req.session.save` was called, you can create a mock function with Jest in this way

```
let req = {
  session: {
    save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined)
  },
};
```

EDIT
I see your connect method is async, but your test is not structured to handle it asynchronously. You should use one of the methodologies explained [> here <](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)